# How to update all Employees records with a sum of current value and one from the input form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I've got this problem. I've got an Employee model that is under namespace Admins
and in the Employee table i have a 'number_of available_kudos' column. Let's say the value of each row is different. And I want to have a form that inputs a value in the range of 1-20 and adds the same value to each row. And the edit and update routes are taken so i've created 2 custom methods like this :

```
module Admins
  class EmployeesController < AdminController
    def index
      @employees = Employee.all
    end

    def edit
      @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit_add_kudos_to_all
      @employee = Employee.all
      render 'admins/employees/update_add_kudos_to_all'
    end

    def update_add_kudos_to_all
      Employee.transaction do
      Employee.find_each do |employee|
        employee.update!(add_kudo_to_all_params)
        employee.number_of_available_kudos =+ employee.number_of_available_kudos
        flash[:notice] = 'Successfully updated the numer of kudos to all employees'

      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
        flash[:notice] = 'The numer of kudos you want to add is too high'
        redirect_to admins_kudo_path
        end
    end
    end

    def destroy
      @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
      flash[:notice] = if @employee.destroy
                         'Employee account was deleted successfully'
                       else
                         'Employee account deletion failed'
                       end
      redirect_to admins_employees_path
    end

    def update
      @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
      if @employee.update(employee_params)
        flash[:notice] = 'Employee was edited successfully'
        redirect_to admins_employees_path
      else
        render 'admins/employees/edit'
      end
    end

    private

    def employee_params
      params.require(:employee).permit(:email, :password, :number_of_available_kudos)
    end

    def add_kudo_to_all_params
      params.fetch(:employee, {} ).permit(:number_of_available_kudos)
    end
  end
end
```

And here are my routes

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins, path: 'admins'
  devise_for :employees, path: 'employees'
  namespace :employees do
    resources :kudos
    resources :rewards, only: [:index, :show]
    resources :orders, only: [:create, :index, :show]
  end
  namespace :admins do
    resources :kudos, only: [:index, :destroy]
    patch 'update_add_kudos_to_all/', to: 'employees#update_add_kudos_to_all'
    get  'edit_add_kudos_to_all/', to: 'employees#edit_add_kudos_to_all'
    resources :employees, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
      resources :orders, only: [:index, :update]
     # patch 'mass_edit/', to: 'mass_edit#update'
     # get 'mass_edit/', to: 'mass_edit#edit'
      end
    namespace :employees do
      resources :orders, only: [:index, :update]
    end
    resources :company_values
    resources :rewards


  end
  get '/admin' => "admins/pages#dashboard", :as => :admin_root
  root 'employees/kudos#index'
end
```

And finally here is my update_add_kudos_to_all form

```
<h1>Edit number of available kudos to all Employees</h1>

<%= form_with url: 'update_add_kudos_to_all', method: :patch  do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%=f.label :number_of_available_kudos %><br/>
    <%= f.number_field :number_of_available_kudos %>  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

Oh and i'll also paste the link_to the edit form

```
<p> <%= link_to 'Add Kudos to all', admins_edit_add_kudos_to_all_path, method: :get %></p>
```

Right now the outcome is that everything is successfull (at least it says it is) and the values don't add up.I can feel i'm missing something basic here. So please help me figure this out.

Comment: At first sight, you have to change the following line:

`employee.number_of_available_kudos =+ employee.number_of_available_kudos`

To:

`employee.number_of_available_kudos += employee.number_of_available_kudos`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But unfortunely in changes nothing in the outcome.

Comment: If you're adding the same values to all the rows you can do a far simpler and more efficient  query where you just update all the rows at once. Something like `UPDATE employees e SET e.number_of_available_kudos = e.number_of_available_kudos  + 10 WHERE e.id IN (?)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you do not need to use strong params. I would write the controller method like this:

```
def update_add_kudos_to_all
  Employee.transaction do
    Employee.find_each do |employee|
      employee.increment(
        :number_of_available_kudos, params[:number_of_available_kudos].to_i
      )
      employee.save!
    end
      
    flash[:notice] = 'Successfully updated the number of kudos to all employees'
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    flash[:notice] = 'The number of kudos you want to add is too high'
    redirect_to admins_kudo_path
  end
end
```

Or, when the validation is not really required, then you can use `update_all` which runs one SQL query and therefore will be much faster:

```
def update_add_kudos_to_all
  Employee.in_batches.update_all(
    "number_of_available_kudos = number_of_available_kudos + #{params[:number_of_available_kudos].to_i}"
  )
end
```

---

To answer your follow-up question from the comments: I would check if the number of new available kudos is valid in the controller and if it is, I would use the `update_all` method as above. But because you asked how to combine it with `update` the following example is a combination of those two approaches:

```
def update_add_kudos_to_all
  new_available_kudos = params[:number_of_available_kudos].to_i

  if (1..20).cover?(new_available_kudos)
    Employee.find_each do |employee|
      employee.update(
        number_of_available_kudos: employee.number_of_available_kudos + new_available_kudos
      )
    end

    flash[:notice] = 'Successfully updated the number of kudos to all employees'
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'Invalid number of kudos, must be between 1 and 20.'
    redirect_to admins_kudo_path
  end
```

Comment: thank you very much it works but out of curoisity how would you write it if I wanted to keep the update method (but not the update_all) and how would you add the constrains for the 1-20 range of addinig kudos ?

Comment: @Wojtek I updated my answer to address your follow-up question.